# How to parse a JSON object into class using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, parsing

My Json Object

```
{"returnStatus":{"code":"0200","status":"SUCCESS","message":"The operation was successful.","requestTime":"20210407141112083","responseTime":"20210407141112256"},"allCities":[{"cityID":2622,"cityName":" UNKNOWN","cityCode":"AAA","area":"KHI"}
```

I want to parse into class.How?
How to get cityID,CityName,cityCode,area etc..

I'm trying this code

```
allCities Cities = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response);
```

Comment: Okay, and? What is the problem with the code you've posted?

Comment: we get this type of error.                                                                                
    Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Comment: The json you posted is not valid (it's missing `"]}"` these closure tags).

Comment: Don't use `dynamic`, unless you really, really have to. Just create a class that represents the JSON, like Ryan Thoma's answer suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Json2CSharp](https://json2csharp.com/) to create classes to deserilalize your object to. You can rename them accordingly if you wish.

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
public class ReturnStatus
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string requestTime { get; set; }
    public string responseTime { get; set; }
}

public class AllCity
{
    public int cityID { get; set; }
    public string cityName { get; set; }
    public string cityCode { get; set; }
    public string area { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public ReturnStatus returnStatus { get; set; }
    public List<AllCity> allCities { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use myDeserializedClass.allCities to access the list of cities.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like Ryan say before an online tool to create classes from your json. But i prefer to use the integrated "Paste Special" Function from Visual Studio.

[image]